# mulitple parameters in perl system function for windows

Tags: windows, perl

I have one scneario where i have to execute one java program & for that i have to first set the class path & all those being invoked under single perl program. I am trying below command which doesn't work:

```
$command1="echo \" First command\"";
$command2="echo \" Second command\"";

system("$command1;$command2");
```

Above command works fine in LINUX but not in windows. Please help me in execution of this.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a good enough problem description, please elaborate. Btw, using a semi-colon inside the `system()` command is a syntax error: Use a comma instead. Or put quotes around the whole thing.

Comment: Or better yet, run the commands individually, with a loop.

Answer (score 2):

On most platforms,

```
system($shell_command);
```

means

```
system('sh', '-c', $shell_command);
```

On Windows, it means something closer to

```
system('cmd', '/x', '/c', $shell_command);
```

### Option 1

Keep using a bourne shell command, but explicitly specify a bourne shell is needed.

```
system('sh', '-c', 'echo 1 ; echo 2');
```

This isn't likely to work since the computer is not likely to have a bourne shell installed.

### Option 2

Use the correct syntax for the local shell.

```
if ($O eq 'MSWin32') {
   system('echo 1 & echo 2');
} else {
   system('echo 1 ; echo 2');
}
```

### Option 3

Call `system` twice.

```
system('echo 1');
system('echo 2');
```

Comment: I can't invoke 2 system commands as my first command sets the environment proprties & dependent on that my second java command invokes.

Comment: Your option sorts out my concern.. Many thanks. i appreciate your skills & competency. Sorry for the question which may look silly to you guys but i have always worked perl in UNIX never in windows so such confusion do occurs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `;` between commands you have to invoke shell. This is alternative to `;`

```
my @cmds =(
  [ "echo",  q{" First command"} ],
  [ "echo",  q{" Second command"} ],
);

system (@$_) for @cmds;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the command. This works fine. Can you please suggest instead of adding the echo commands directly to the list whether we can place it in any varaible first & than pass those variables to the list @cmds?? If possible please share the command. I am trying something like 
$com1="echo \"First command\"\n"; 
$com2="echo \"Second command\"\n"; 
my @cmds=($com1,$com2); 
system(@$_) for @cmds;
I didn't work.. :(

Comment: The contents of @cmds aren't array references in your example. Try: `system($_) for @cmds;`

Comment: @Ashish I wouldn't do this as your suggestion invokes shell unnecessarily.

Comment: @mpapec, `echo` is a shell builtin on Windows. Your code shouldn't work on Windows. A bug in Windows's version of `system` allows it to work, though.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are trying

```
$a=" echo wasssup people";
$b=" echo hi guys";
system("$a"."$b");
```

Comment: This will give you "wasssup people echo hi guys", probably not what he wants.